# How to "Add" two bytes together

Tags: c#, byte

I have an odd scenario (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657388/opennetcf-signature-control-question/2667719#2667719) for more details), where I need to add two bytes of data together.  Obviously this is not normal adding.  Here is the scenario:

I am trying to get a coordinate out of a control.  When the control is less that 256 in width then the x coordinate takes one byte, otherwise it takes two bites.

So, I now have an instance of that control that is larger than 256 in width.  How do I add these two numbers together?

So for example:

- 2 + 0 is not 2 because the 2 is the high byte (or maybe it is the low byte and it is 2...)

Am I making sense?  If so, how can I do this kind of addition in C#?

---

Update: Sorry for the confusing question.  I think I got it figured out.  See my answer below.

Comment: "Am I making sense?": no, absolutely not... why are you using bytes in the first place, rather than a more adequate type like int ?

Comment: ...huh?  why are you worrying about bytes at all?  Width is an integer.

Comment: I bet you 1,000,000.00 that you can solve it with a `bool` variable.

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan - maybe, but I would need about 1,000,000 bools.

Comment: One byte, two bites, 8 is a whole meal :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach with multiplying is pretty clear but not common in bitwise word, and your approach with BitConverter takes byte array which is not convenient in many cases.

The most common (and easy way) to perform this - use bitwise operators:

```
var r = (high << 8) | low;
```

And remember about [byte ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) because it's not always obvious which byte is high and which is low.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like

```
256 * high + low
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else needs this, I was looking for:

```
BitConverter.ToInt16
```

[It takes two bytes and converts them to an integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint16.aspx).

Comment: And why in the world would you need that at all?  That's what I am interested in hearing...

Comment: @Ed Swangren - good question.  It is, unfortunately a long answer.  If you read this question you will see what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657388/opennetcf-signature-control-question  (More specifically the 3rd comment on that question)